# Value of var goes back to empty after exiting function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

So I have an api request inside of a function thats placed in my Service script.. I have defined the variable "curruser" outside of the function so I can keep its value, however after exiting the follow Scirpt, curruser is empty??

services.js

```
function fbUserInfo() {
  ngFB.api({
    path: '/me',
    params: {
      fields: '/*params*/'
    }
  }).then(
    function(user) {
      curruser = user;

      $http.get(/*send GET request to my server*/).success(function(response) {
        if (response.length < 20) {
          curruser.firsttime = true;
        } else {
          curruser.firsttime = false;
        }
        console.log(curruser);
        console.log("1");
      });
    },

    function(error) {
      alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
    });
}
```

So the console.log would return the proper JSON object I retrieved from facebook.. but when I return it in  the return statement

```
return {
  userInfo: function() {
    fbUserInfo();
    console.log(curruser);
    return curruser;
  }
```

it returns that curruser is an empty object! I did write

```
var curruser;
```

into the first line inside the ".factory"

Answer (score 0):

you have to use then() since fbUserInfo() is async function

```
return {
  userInfo: function() {
    $.when(fbUserInfo())..then(
function(user) {
  curruser = user;

  $http.get(/*send GET request to my server*/).success(function(response) {
    if (response.length < 20) {
      curruser.firsttime = true;
    } else {
      curruser.firsttime = false;
    }
    console.log(curruser);
    console.log("1");
  });
},

function(error) {
  alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
}).then(function(){
 console.log(curruser);
    return curruser;
})

  }
```

Comment: this doesnt work, tells me "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @user1386579 `fbUserInfo` function returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but might work.

```
    var curruser;
    function fbUserInfo( callback ) {
      ngFB.api({
        path: '/me',
        params: {
          fields: '/*params*/'
        }
      }).then(
        function(user) {
          curruser = user;

          $http.get(/*send GET request to my server*/).success(function(response) {
            if (response.length < 20) {
              curruser.firsttime = true;
            } else {
              curruser.firsttime = false;
            }
            console.log(curruser);
            console.log("1");
            callback(curruser);
          });
        },

        function(error) {
          alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
        });
    }


return {
  userInfo: function( callback ) {
    fbUserInfo( function(data){
       console.log(data);
       callback(data);
    });
  }
```